# Honda Civic 2014 EX Block Heater

Tags: honda, civic, block-heater

I have a 2014 Honda Civic Ex Sedan. The dealer installed a block engine heater before the last winter. When they finished the installation, I had 2 cables like these:

[image: Female and male connector]

These cables were going out from the bottom of the bumper like this

[image]

***But as you can see, there is only the male connector now.***

Can someone tell me where can I find the female connector? I mean this (the picture below is a reference. It's not for cars)

[image: Female connector]

What kind of cord is it? AND the most important thing, where do I connect it under the hood?

I didn't know that the female connector could be removed easily and it's a shame that someone stole it.

I went to Canadian Tire but they didn't know of what I was talking about. I called the dealer to explain what happened, but they told me that I need to buy a new block heater package (around $100).

I tried to do a research on Internet but I cannot find anything about it. I reviewed my installation bill and I found the generic product code 08T44-SNA-301, but curiously it doesn't come with the female connector. This is the [link](http://www.bernardiparts.com/Images/Install/2014_CivicSedan_EngineBlockHeater_AII50693.pdf) where you can find the details of the product and how to install it in the car.

I think newer models of honda include a place to connect the female cord or maybe a connector to the battery.

The male connector has a sticker that it says **"pyroil" 1752 10amp 125v 1250w**

I live in Canada by the way.

Thanks

Comment: The third picture is what it looks like now? Or is that the part which was "removed" from your car? As an aside, this looks like a shopping question, which is off topic for the site.

Comment: It's what it looks like now. The inlet cable is already missing. Not only a shopping question, it's also a technical question. Where to connect the inlet cable in the Honda.

Comment: Is [this what you're looking for](http://images.oreillyauto.com/parts/img/medium/zro/3600007_wh.jpg)?

Comment: No. That's what I already have in the picture 3. I'm looking for the picture 2. The female cord to plug the connector that you are suggesting on your picture. They are 2 differents cables. The one that you are suggesting is the cable that is connected to the block engine which match with my picture 1 and 3. But there is another cable (female) that provides the power and is connected to the car.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to tell you this, *but any 12/3 extension cord* (15A or better) will do what you need. I see nothing there which you need *anything* special to get your block heater attached to AC power. I grew up in a cold environment (Northern Rockies in Montana). *All* our cars had block heaters. We *never* had anything special beyond the male plug you've shown in the third picture to plug our cars in. Grab an extension cord and find out for yourself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me it's convenient to have that extension cord inside the car(I mean inside the hood), because I don't have a house with a garage so I rent an appartment and I don't have any power outlet near to connect my engine heater. The picture that you uploaded is exactly what it looked like before. Both cables were going out from the front grille as in the picture 3 of my question. But last week when I picked up my car to go home I found that the cable from the left was missing. Both were attached with a strong rubber band. I didn't know that someone could steal or need that

Comment: Furthermore, If I could buy a regular extension cord in a dollar store... I need to know where to connect it carefully.

Comment: Anything I say at this point is going to sound condescending. The part which is stuck out of the grill ... follow it back and ensure the other end is attached to the block heater. After that, all you *have* to do is plug in the extension cord to that bit and you're golden. And don't get any ole regular cord ... get you a 12/3 15A cord. You'll probably need one at 100' (or 30m ... however you measure in Canada). The male end of the extension cord is up to you. Also, that thing which is hanging off to the side which is attached to your male end sticking out of the grill ... use that as a cover.